# PHP Help - MIME Code?

Tags: php, mime

I want to download complete webpage using MIME code. I am using

```
header("Content-type:application/msword");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; Filename=$profile_id.doc");
```

to download webpage in MS Word and I am trying:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; Filename=$profile_id.pdf");
```

to download webpage in PDF, but the PDF one is not working. Please tell me how to do so...thanks :)

I think that this code is deprecated now. Please let me know th substitute code of this

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-type-for-pdf-files

Comment: what is your problem exactly ? do you correctly output a pdf binary stream ?

Comment: Jerome...No sir, I am not getting correct output in case of PDF file...the file gets downloaded but not in correct format..so it doesn't open in Acrobat Reader

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
header('Content-Type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="'.$profile_id.'.pdf"');
```

**Edited:**
Try, something like:

```
$file = $profile_id.".pdf";
header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="'.$profile_id.'.pdf"');
```

Comment: @OP: Yes, or wrap the variable in {} so the parser can see which bits are meant to be a variable :)

Comment: Sudhir sir...i tried it...

header("Content-Disposition:attachment; Filename=$profile_id.pdf");

is working properly but not 

"header('Content-Type:application/pdf');"