# How to make <input type="file"/> accept only these types?

Tags: html, file-upload, input

I want my uploader only allows these types:

- doc, docx.
- xls, xlsx.
- ppt, pptx.
- txt.
- pdf.
- Image types.

How can I achieve this? What should I put in the `accept` attribute? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT!!!**

I have one more thing to ask. When the popup appears for use to choose file, at the down right corner, there is a drop down list contains all allow files. In my case, the list would be long. I see in the list, there is an option called `All Supported Types`. How can I make it chosen by default and eliminate all other options?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601342/upload-doc-or-pdf-using-php. Not sure if "application/doc", "application/pdf", and "application/ppt" mime types are supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question:
"The accept attribute doesn't validate the types of the selected files; it simply provides hints for browsers to guide users towards selecting the correct file types. It is still possible (in most cases) for users to toggle an option in the file chooser that makes it possible to override this and select any file they wish, and then choose incorrect file types. Because of this, you should make sure that the accept attribute is backed up by appropriate server-side validation."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Answer (score 190):

The value of the [`accept` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#accept) is, as per HTML5 LC, a [comma-separated list of items, each of which is a specific media type like `image/gif`, or a notation like `image/*` that refers to all `image` types, or a filename extension like `.gif`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Unique_file_type_specifiers). IE 10+ and Chrome support all of these, whereas Firefox does not support the extensions. Thus, the safest way is to use [media types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) and notations like `image/*`, in this case

```
<input type="file" name="foo" accept=
"application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
text/plain, application/pdf, image/*">
```

if I understand the intents correctly. Beware that browsers might not recognize the media type names exactly as specified in the authoritative registry, so some testing is needed.

Comment: This will not work if your doc file made with ubuntu software.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela that filter gets me all the office files i want,thank you

Comment: To add suport for docx, xlsx and pptx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow

Comment: Maybe it was true in 2014 when this answer was given, but I can confirm that a comma separated list of extensions is working correctly on Firefox.

Comment: did not work when try to upload from android/ios device. If anybody has a solution let me know.

Comment: just tested application/msword it doesnt accept .docx documents, which are very common now when downloading from microsoft office online (free version).

Comment: docx not supporting with 'application/msword'. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 141):

Use Like below

```
<input type="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf" />
```

Comment: Browsers usually do not check the file content, so extension is ok - even preferred since browsers do not know all the mime types..  You have to check the file content yourself.

Comment: not worked in mac thanks

Answer (score 14):

IMPORTANT UPDATE:

Due to use of only application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint... allows only till 2003 MS products, and not newest. I've found this:

```
application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
```

And that includes the new ones. For other files, you can retrieve the MIME TYPE in your file by this way (pardon the lang)(in MIME list types, there aren't this ones):

[image]

You can select & copy the type of content

Comment: why not to just write extensions?

Answer (score 13):

Use accept attribute with the MIME_type as values

```
<input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: The code given accepts only GIF and JPEG files, as opposite to what was requested for in the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, This is just sample code and you can set the `accept` attribute with the `MIME_type`s as values

Comment: This still presents an "All Files" option.

Answer (score 9):

for powerpoint and pdf files:

```
<html>
<input type="file" placeholder="Do you have a .ppt?" name="pptfile" id="pptfile" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

As [stated on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp):

> audio/*   - All sound files are accepted
>
> video/*   - All video files are accepted
>
> image/*   - All image files are accepted
>
> MIME_type - A valid MIME type, with no parameters. Look at IANA MIME
>   types for a complete list of standard MIME types

Comment: @MateusLeon Lose not loose.

Comment: @reformed what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex78191 I was addressing MateusLeon's comment, which appears to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [complete list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) of `MIME Type` formats according to extension.

- `.doc`: application/msword
- `.docx`: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- `.json`: application/json
- `.txt`: text/plain
- ...

Example:

```
<input type="file" accept='application/msword, text/plain' />
```

Answer (score -2):

for image write this

```
<input type=file accept="image/*">
```

For other,
You can use the accept attribute on your form to suggest to the browser to restrict certain types. However, you'll want to re-validate in your server-side code to make sure. Never trust what the client sends you

Comment: The code given accepts only image files, as opposite to what was requested for in the question.