# Allow only pdf, doc, docx format for file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am triggering a file upload on href click.
I am trying to block all extension except doc, docx and pdf.
I am not getting the correct alert value.

```
<div class="cv"> Would you like to attach you CV? <a href="" id="resume_link">Click here</a></div>
    <input type="file" id="resume" style="visibility: hidden">
```

Javascript:

```
        var myfile="";
        $('#resume_link').click(function() {
            $('#resume').trigger('click');
            myfile=$('#resume').val();
            var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
            //var extension = myfile.substr( (myfile.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );

            if(ext=="pdf" || ext=="docx" || ext=="doc"){
                alert(ext);
            }
            else{
                alert(ext);
            }
         })
```

[MyFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSQ9H/)..its showing error

Comment: I don't think that will work in all browsers. If you use HTML5 you can use the attribute `accept`.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work at all for me. You need to close the `<input>` tag at least.

Comment: @Rup `<input>` tags are self-closing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make <input type="file"/> accept only these types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293861/how-to-make-input-type-file-accept-only-these-types)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Better to use `change` event on input field.

Updated source:

```
var myfile="";

$('#resume_link').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#resume').trigger('click');
});

$('#resume').on( 'change', function() {
   myfile= $( this ).val();
   var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
   if(ext=="pdf" || ext=="docx" || ext=="doc"){
       alert(ext);
   } else{
       alert(ext);
   }
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSQ9H/21/).

Comment: no no no...its correct..i just made a mistake while uploading the syntax

Comment: OK, fair enough. Please either fix your fiddle, or tell us what error you're actually seeing (behaviour and script errors), or both - because it's not currently possible for us to reproduce it.

Comment: my fiddle is not working its showing error `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`...and i am just not able to get the alert of my extension??there is no syntax error..

Comment: @MESSIAH Because of `<a>` element reloads iframe, so `e.preventDefault()` fix this problem.

Comment: If the document were to be renamed with extension in DOCX, this would not work.

Answer (score 89):

You can use

```
<input name="Upload Saved Replay" type="file" 
  accept="application/pdf,application/msword,
  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
```

whearat

- `application/pdf` means `.pdf`
- `application/msword` means `.doc`
- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` means `.docx`

instead.

[EDIT] Be warned, `.dot` might match too.

Comment: will this accept doc and docx...and i dont need to write any validation for this?

Comment: See, if the client-os dont know about what is the mime-type of `.pdf`-files, it won't show `.pdf`-files for selection! You can use the `navigator.mimeType` to evaluate this cornercase.

Comment: Safari and IE9 and older dont support this attribute.  I suspect IE10 doesn't either but I can't remember specifically.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp sais ie10 accept. You are right, ie9 doesnt accept.

Comment: The user can still select "all files" in the explorer window, and then be able to upload whatever file he/she wants. This doesnt validate the format, its just a  "starting pont" of what files are visible in the explorer window while selecting a file

Answer (score 7):

For only acept files with extension doc and docx in the explorer window try this

```
    <input type="file" id="docpicker"
  accept=".doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

Comment: That's just a hint though, not a firm restriction. You can still choose a file with a different extension.in the dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

Below code worked for me:

```
<input #fileInput type="file" id="avatar" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />

application/pdf means .pdf
application/msword means .doc
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document means .docx
```

Comment: I downvoted. Today, id like to remove my downvote because I know now the meaning of `#fileInput`. Furthermore I do like to upvote becasue it is indeed helpful and I was wrong in downvote the answer! Unfortuantely I can not upvote the answer nor remove the downvote. Because `Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`. In the reality, I do think this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" multiple={true} id="file"  onChange={this.addFile.bind(this)} accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,.ppt, .pptx"/>
```

React code - file attached and set files in state:

```
     @autobind
      private addFile(event) {
     for(var j=0;j<event.target.files.length;j++){
          var _size = event.target.files[j].size;
          var fSExt = new Array('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'),
          i=0;while(_size>900){_size/=1024;i++;}
          var exactSize = (Math.round(_size*100)/100)+' '+fSExt[i];
          var date = event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate,
          mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
          day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
          date=[day,mnth,date.getFullYear()].join("/");
          fileinformation.push({
            "file_name":  event.target.files[j].name,
            "file_size": exactSize,
            "file_modified_date":date
          });
          var ext = event.target.files[j].name.split('.').pop();
          if(ext=="pdf" || ext=="docx" || ext=="doc"|| ext=="ppt"|| ext=="pptx"){
            
          } else{
            iscorrectfileattached=false;
          }
        }
        if(iscorrectfileattached==false){
          alert("Only PFD, Word and PPT file can be attached.");
          return false;
        }
   this.setState({fileinformation});
    //new code end
    var date = event.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate,
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    date=[day,mnth,date.getFullYear()].join("/");
    this.setState({filesize:exactSize});
    this.setState({filedate:date});
    //let resultFile = document.getElementById('file');
    let resultFile = event.target.files;
    console.log(resultFile);
    let fileInfos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < resultFile.length; i++) {
      var fileName = resultFile[i].name;
      console.log(fileName);
      var file = resultFile[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(file) {
         return function(e) {
              //Push the converted file into array
               fileInfos.push({
                  "name": file.name,
                  "content": e.target.result
                  });
                };
         })(file); 
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    this.setState({fileInfos});
    this.setState({FileNameValue:  event.target.files[0].name });
    //this.setState({IsDisabled:  true });//for multiple file

    console.log(fileInfos);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = form.getForm().findField("file").getValue();
var fileLen = file.length;
var lastValue = file.substring(fileLen - 3, fileLen);
if (lastValue == 'doc') {//check same for other file format}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make it by REGEX:

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="uploadExtensionError" style="display: none">Only PDF allowed!</div>
    <input type="file" name="item_file" />
    <input type="submit" id='submit' value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And java script validation:

```
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        var val = $('input[type=file]').val().toLowerCase();
        var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(pdf|docx|doc)$");
        if(!(regex.test(val))) {
            $('.uploadExtensionError').show();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.file){
        let img = req.file ;
       if(img.mimetype != "application/pdf" && img.mimetype != "application/msword" && img.mimetype != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"){
       throw {message :"Please enter only pdf and docx file"}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $('#resume_link').click(function() {
        var ext = $('#resume').val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ["doc","pdf",'docx']) == -1) {
            // false
        }else{
            // true
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Can you highlight what you've changed? Apart from the refactor / rearrange it looks like it's just the `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: @Rup if($.inArray(ext, ["doc","pdf",'docx']) == -1) looked here

Comment: did you just ripped it off from other question..i just saw the exact answer on some other question..

Comment: @MESSIAH up-vote if you think it help you to solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('#surat_lampiran').bind('change', function() {
  alerr = "";
  sts = false;
  alert(this.files[0].type);
  if(this.files[0].type != "application/pdf" && this.files[0].type != "application/msword" && this.files[0].type != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"){
  sts = true;
  alerr += "Jenis file bukan .pdf/.doc/.docx ";
}
});
```