# How to make a file field that only accept pdf and doc

Tags: html, cross-platform, http-accept-language

I need to accept only pdf and doc file using input type file.

```
<input type="file" id="test" name="test" accept="application/msword,text/plain, application/pdf"/>
```

This is working in windows, but in ubunthu, it only accept pdf file

Comment: try to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992586/allow-only-pdf-doc-docx-format-for-file-upload

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<input type="file" id="test" name="test" accept=".pdf,.doc"/>
```

The extensions should start with a *dot* `"."` and separated by a *comma* `","`

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***accept*** attribute for performing this task.
Example:-

`<input type="file" id="example" name="test" accept=".pdf,.docx"/>`

Just as simple as it is.

Comment: It looks like they already know about `accept`, the problem is browser compatibility