# allow file with a specific filename and extension to be uploaded

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I need to check that the filename has to be uploaded only if it has the specific name and a specific extension. How do i do that? For example: I can upload file only if it has filename: can_to_do and extension: pdf else it will send out an alert asking us to change the filename

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make <input type="file"/> accept only these types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293861/how-to-make-input-type-file-accept-only-these-types)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i need to upload jrxml file extension. so the validation goes something like that. say file name `someFile.jrxml`

```
var fileVal = $('#fileId').val();
    if (fileVal != null && fileVal != '')
         {
           var ext = fileVal.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
           if ($.inArray(ext, ['jrxml']) == -1) {
              jAlert('Not a valid file');
              isOk = false;
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this question I posted that is to be able to upload only if the file has a particular filename and extension. Here, for example: "ReleaseNotes.txt".  It is in Javascript:

```
 function uploadFile() 
    {
    var fileElement = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
            var x = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
            var txt = "";
          if ('files' in x) {
          if (x.files.length != 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
          var file = x.files[i];
          if ('name' in file) {
          if (file.name == "ReleaseNotes.txt")
          {
          alert("pass");    
          }
          else{
          alert("fail");
    }   
}
```