# Accept attribute for input[type=file] allows other extensions

Tags: html, file

Anybody knows why this input accepts .php file extensions?

( At least in the latest version of chrome )

```html
<input type="file" accept=".doc,.pdf,.txt,.rtl">
```

[image]

Comment: Please Refer this, it says use file types rather than extensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293861/how-to-make-input-type-file-accept-only-these-types

Comment: FWIW, a `.php` file basically *is* a `.txt` file for all intends and purposes… Chrome's behaviour isn't even wrong.

Comment: check type of your file with checkfiletype.com it should be MIME Type: text/plain;

Comment: @deceze, no, the file extension should be taken into consideration, not the MIME when you set `.any`. `.txt` can be anything. Note that if you do rename an `image/png`to `file.txt`, chrome will still show it as accepted

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but that's debatable. A .txt file contains pure text. A .php file contains pure text. Po-tay-to, po-tah-to… :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a Mac Os only bug.
I wasn't able to reproduce it from my win10 VM, but it is still there in v.55.0.2861.0 canary.

---

The problem seems to come from the `.txt`.
It's like it will accept any `text/*` files, when this extension is set.

You can star [this chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646941) which treats of the same underlying issue (with a different extension).

```html
<input type="file" accept=".txt">
```

Comment: Nice, removed the .txt and it's now how I expected. thanks for the clarification !

Comment: @kaiido what would the approach be if you were to allow `txt` files to be uploaded but not `js`? I have tried `text/plain` but this didn't work