# Prevent uploading JavaScript files with ng file upload

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

Using the [ng file upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive I'm using ngf-accept to specify a list of allowed file types.  This has disallowed many file types and they appear grey in the upload dialog but I'm still able to upload any files with a .js or a .sh extension.

I've added the directive to the following link, with the list of allowed files.

```
<a ng-model="file" data-nodrag ngf-select="openUploadModal($file, this)" ng-show="this.$nodeScope.$modelValue.type === 'folder'" ngf-accept="'image/*,video/*,audio/*,.pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx'">
```

The problem comes from the .txt allowed value. If I remove the '.txt' extension the .js and .sh files are also disabled.  Apparently [this is due to a bug affecting Mac users only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508849/accept-attribute-for-inputtype-file-allows-other-extensions), but is there any way around this?

Comment: Note that said plugin will not prevent users from skipping your client-side protections and uploading whatever your server will allow directly to the server via the same endpoint.

Comment: yes, I have server side protection but want to avoid the client side error for people who are not poking around with the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than ngf-accept, try ngf-pattern and then you can use '!' to explicitly disable certain file types:

```
<a ng-model="file" data-nodrag ngf-select="openUploadModal($file, this)" ng-show="this.$nodeScope.$modelValue.type === \'folder\'" ngf-pattern="'image/*,video/*,audio/*,.pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,!.js,!.sh'">
```