# Restricting HTML file input to accept only .txt, and not .csv (in Chrome)

Tags: html, csv, text, input

I tried to filter file format to accept only `.txt` in HTML. Here's my HTML code:

```
<Input
 type="file"
 accept="text/plain"
/>
```

In Safari, it works and only `.txt` files show up, but in Chrome (63.0.3239.84) the file selector also shows `.csv` files.

Is it possible to exclude `.csv` files in Chrome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `accept` attribute specifies the types of files that the form input will accept.

#### Syntax

```
<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">
```

> Tip: To specify more than one value, separate the values with a comma (e.g. .

---

#### Solution

Simply include the filetype you'd like to allow in the `accept` attribute, as follows:

```
<input accept=".txt"
```

> Note: Because this file-restriction is client-side, users are able to remove this attribute and bypass this file-restriction, potentially leading to a vulnerability.

Comment: thanks for response I tried the suggestion,
but accept=".txt" will include '.csv' in Chrome, 
even include '.docx' in Safari

Comment: See my edit for additional methods of solving this problem.

Comment: as I tried (on Mac),
accept="text/plain" in Safari will get the result I expect (exclude .csv)
and Chrome both accept '.txt', 'text/plain' will shows .csv file.

I guess I can only give some placeholder or tooltip to user,
anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: This syntax still allow users to attach `.js` `.py` files, etc.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for Chrome anymore. I'm on 86.0.4240.183.

Comment: There seems to be a bug around this in macOS Chromium. See [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646941), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508849/accept-attribute-for-inputtype-file-allows-other-extensions) related question.

Comment: The above solution doesn't work in Chrome Version 95.0.4638.54
Is there an alternate way to show only .txt and exclude .csv in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Its a chrome and mac os bug, Please refer and vote it.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1353740

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but I think it will work:

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt"/>
```