# PHP upload MIME type restrictions

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a file upload system in a site which allows upload of .doc, .docs and .pdf files. Currently the PHP script allows upload of any file type. I would like to restrict it to only allow uploading of genuine PDF DOC and DOCX files. I have read that this is best done via checking the MIME type / headers of the file - but cant seem to find an agreed best solution to do this anywhere.

Any tips on the best way to achieve this?

Current upload PHP is:

```
$meta = $dropbox->UploadFile($_FILES["fileInputFieldName"]["tmp_name"], $upload_name);
```

Appreciate any tips on how to integrate this into the suggestions please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601342/upload-doc-or-pdf-using-php

Comment: use if condition on the file name extension.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you try the below code

```
$sys = mime_content_type($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($sys == 'application/x-zip' || $sys == 'application/msword'){
    echo ' allowed';
}else{
    echo 'not allowed';
}
```

Comment: You can use finfo_file if you are using PHP5 and above .

Comment: Thanks Justin, so, to implement this to my usage - which elements do I change to reflect my fileupload system. Why do we need a "tmp_name" element?

Comment: @dubbs `tmp_name` is not an element. It is image property

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the end for those interested:

```
$allowedExts = array(
  "pdf", 
  "doc", 
  "docx"
); 

$allowedMimeTypes = array( 
  'application/msword',
  'application/pdf',
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
  'application/x-pdf',
  'application/vnd.pdf',
  'text/pdf'
);

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ( ! ( in_array($extension, $allowedExts ) ) ) {
  die('Please provide another file type [E/2].');
}

if ( in_array( $_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimeTypes ) ) 
{      
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
}
else
{
die('Please provide another file type [E/3].');
}
```

Comment: But just tested and I took a JPG file and gave it a .pdf file extension and it passed this validation...???

Comment: This is not safe: the `type` property is sent by the browser and can be faked, or fall afoul of browsers incorrectly recognizing the type (that's probably what happened in the JPG vs. PDF case). Justin's answer is the only safe one.

Answer (score 0):

```
that is how i restrict extension for image, you can apply this for doc and other files you want.. 

 "i converted $_FILES to $file"

if ($file['profile_pic']['error'] == 0) {
                                         // echo 'hello';
                                $fileName = strtolower($file['profile_pic']['name']);
                                $fileType = $file['profile_pic']['type'];
                                $tempName = $file['profile_pic']['tmp_name'];
                                $fileSize = $file['profile_pic']['size'];

                                $fileExtArray = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'public.jpeg');
                                $random_no = mt_rand() * 64;
                                $uploaddir = '../../Application/img/';
                                $file_name = $random_no . "_profile_" . $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];
                                $image = $uploaddir . basename($file_name);
                                if (in_array($fileType, $fileExtArray))
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_pic']['tmp_name'], $image);
                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $allowedExts = array("bmp", "gif", "jpg","png","jpeg");
                            $RandomNum   = rand(0, 9999);           
                            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['uploadedimage']['name']));
                            $ImageType      = $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type']; //"document/txt", document/doc etc.
                            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                            $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                            if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"]))
                            {
                                if(!in_array($ImageExt, $allowedExts))
                                {
                                    $message.="<span class='error-message'>Invalid file format of image, only <b>'bmp', 'gif', 'jpg','png','jpeg'</b> allowed.</span><br>";
                                }
                            }
                            if(isset($message) && $message=='')
                            {
                                //image
                                $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
                                $imagename=time().'-'.$ImageName;
                                $target_path = "../profile-images/".$imagename;
                                $_SESSION['message']=$message;  
                                }
```