# Mime Type PDF php upload

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

I have this snippet

```
if ($_FILES['tax']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['tax']['error']);
}
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['tax']['tmp_name']);
    $ok = false;
    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/gif':
        case 'application/pdf':
        case 'image/png':
        $ok = true;
        default:
    die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tax"]["tmp_name"],"pints/" . $_FILES["tax"]["name"]);
```

When I try to upload the image it states that it isn't a permitted file type, when the file is a PDF document, is `application/pdf` the correct mime type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper MIME type for PDF files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-type-for-pdf-files)

Comment: $mime = $_FILES["file"]["type"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to break before the default case :)

By the way, for the sake of answering your direct question, I've found myself referring back to this thread over and over again: [Proper MIME media type for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-type-for-pdf-files)

Comment: I checked out that question that's why I was confused about if it was right or not. But thank you! Forgetting the breaks was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try this and

```
 if ($_FILES['tax']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['tax']['error']);

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['tax']['tmp_name']);
    $ok = false;
    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/gif':
        break;
        case 'application/pdf':
        break;
        case 'image/png':
            $ok = true;
        break;
        default:
            die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
        break;
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tax"]["tmp_name"],"pints/" . $_FILES["tax"]["name"]);
```

If won't solve your problem then tell us how do `finfo_open` and `finfo_file` functions look like.