# htaccess configuration not configured correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration

I have a directory structure:
httpdocs/documents/folder1
httpdocs/documents/folder2
httpdocs/documents/folder3

etc in httpdocs/document I have a .ht access file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(PDF)$ fileopen.php
```

and in this folder I have fileopen.php

This file then opens pdf files in folder1 to folder3 depending on a $_Get request sent by a file request in the httpdocs folder.

I want the htaccess file to limit access to all folders but allow any pdf being requested by fileopen.php to be downloaded and opened.  Is this possible cause I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is possible to block it using `mod_rewrite` rules. I guess most simple and robust solution is to **move `folder1, folder2, folder3` outside DOCUMENT_ROOT**.

Then you can have `httpdocs` and a new `pdfdir` at same level. `pfdir` can then contain `folder1, folder2, folder3`.

Something like this:

```
---> httpdocs/
----------> .htaccess
----------> fileopen.php
----------> documents/
---> pdfdir/
----------> folder1/
-------------------> foo.PDF
----------> folder2/
-------------------> bar.PDF
----------> folder3/
-------------------> baz.PDF
```

This way `pdfdir` and its contents are inaccessible from web and your `index.php` can still access them using `fopen` etc file functions.

Comment: I didn't want to use stuff outside the webroot but wanted to try to make htaccess work- however I gave up putting it outside the webroot was pretty straightforward and like you say robust thanks

Comment: You're welcome, keeping those files outside is way more secured than any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(PDF)$ fileopen.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2|folder3) - [L,F]
```

Comment: @user1616338 it's up to your `fileopen.php` script to [return the proper content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files) then read and output the pdf file.