# write string to pdf file

Tags: java, spring, pdf, io, stream

I need to write a String object "plain text" to a pdf file from a java program, does java or spring have any built-in libraries that can do the job.if not what are the best choice external libraries?
I know I can use `FileOutputStream` to write data to a file but is there any option that can format the data in pdf and write it to the file, like `.setContentType("application/pdf")` of the `HttpServletResponse`
 thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, but a hint is that you will have to convert it from plain text to a binary (or semi-binary) format since pdf's are not plain text. You have to find an algorithm or formula that does that, and without a library you will have to provide that. When conversion to (semi)binary is done, you can write that text to the file.

Comment: What does "write a string" mean? You cannot "just" write any old text into a PDF file without breaking it.

Comment: [A minimal pdf](http://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0004.html) and the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit/update a PDF document and you dont want to use any libraries, then you will have to implement the PDF specs yourself.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format

However, doesn't look very simple. So I would recommend not to reinvent the wheel and to use libraries like iText.

Regarding the mime type, yes it is `application/pdf`. More details here [Proper MIME media type for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)