# python-requests and EchoSign

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to post a file into EchoSign APIs and it works everywhere for me except for python-requests.

I have here the CURL command that works perfectly

```py
curl -H "Access-Token: API_KEY" \
 -F File=@/home/user/Desktop/test123.pdf \
 https://secure.echosign.com/api/rest/v2/transientDocuments
```

and this is my requests function. It will upload the PDF file but with garbage whereas CURL works perfectly.

```py
api_url = 'https://secure.echosign.com/api/rest/v2'

def send_document(file_path, access_token=access_token):
    """Uploads document to EchoSign and returns its ID

   :param access_token: EchoSign Access Token
   :param file_path: Absolute or relative path to File
   :return string: Document ID

   """
    headers = {'Access-Token': access_token}

    url = api_url + '/transientDocuments'

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        files = {
            'File': f,
        }
        return requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files).json().get('transientDocumentId')
```

What am I doing wrong?? I have tried posting the file as data instead of files too and still no different result

Thanks

**EDIT**

It worked when I added

```py
data = {
    'Mime-Type': 'application/pdf',
    'File-Name': 'abc.pdf'
}
```

So, my new function would be:

```py
def send_document(file_path, access_token=access_token):
    """Uploads document to EchoSign and returns its ID

    :param access_token: EchoSign Access Token
    :param file_path: Absolute or relative path to File
    :return string: Document ID

    """
    headers = {
        'Access-Token': access_token,
    }
    data = {
        'Mime-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'File-Name': 'abc.pdf'
    }
    url = api_url + '/transientDocuments'
    files = {'File': open(file_path, 'rb')}
    return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data,
                         files=files).json().get('transientDocumentId')
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "It will upload the PDF file but with garbage"? If you make the same requests against https://httpbin.org/post you'll see requests produces identical requests.

Comment: It will display a PDF file with all weird characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works

```
def send_document(file_path, access_token=access_token):
    """Uploads document to EchoSign and returns its ID

    :param access_token: EchoSign Access Token
    :param file_path: Absolute or relative path to File
    :return string: Document ID

    """
    headers = {
        'Access-Token': access_token,
    }
    data = {
        'Mime-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'File-Name': 'abc.pdf'
    }
    url = api_url + '/transientDocuments'
    files = {'File': open(file_path, 'rb')}
    return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data,
                         files=files).json().get('transientDocumentId')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the filename and mime-type, like so:

```
files = {
    'File': (
        os.path.basename(file_path),
        f,
        'application/pdf',
    )
}
```

References:

- http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file
- `man curl`, see the `--trace-file FILE` argumet
- [Proper MIME media type for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)