# attach a pdf to an email in meteor

Tags: pdf, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to attach a pdf file but giving errors on server startup. I want avoid saving the file locally first.
it is using pascoual:pdfkit.
The error I am getting is:

> Error: Message failed: 421 Timeout waiting for data from client.

Meteor doc point to  [mailcomposer documentation](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/blob/v4.0.1/README.md#attachments), but the issue is how to integrate the pdf doc in the attachments. Any ideas? Thanks

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Invoice.email();
};

// invoice.js
use strict";
let PDFDocument = require ('pdfkit');
let metaData = {
  'Title': 'Invoice',
  'Author': 'myName',
};
export const Invoice = {
  'make': function () {
    let doc = new PDFDocument(metaData);
    doc.text('my company').text('company number');

    return doc;
  },
  'email': function () {
    let inv = Invoice.make();
    Email.send({
      to: 'myemail@comp.com',
      from: 'personal@company.com',
      subject: 'Invoice',
      text: ' Please see the attached invoice',
      attachments: {
        filename: 'invoice.pdf',
        content: inv // <=== this is the issue
     });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Documentation, the `content` definition is

> **content** - String, Buffer or a Stream contents for the attachment

Link to [mailcomposer documentation.](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/blob/v4.0.1/README.md#attachments)

If I am not wrong the `Invoice.make()` is not returning expecting format of blob. Kindly check the Stream and type so that you know you get what you are creating.

Link to more [Supporting details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)