# PDF from PUT in new window via Blob URI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

I have an API endpoint which on a PUT serves a PDF with `Content-Type "application/pdf"` (you might ask "why a PUT and not a GET?" and the answer to that is "it’s complicated and I can’t change it").

I want to (client side), request that PDF and display the result in a `window.open()` call (ie display the PDF in a new window).  Previously I used a data URI to do this, ie:

```
window.open('data:application/pdf,<the data payload from the response>');
```

but in Chrome 60 this no longer works (you can’t use a data URI in a `window.open`, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751135 ).

I have now changed the client side code to do a `fetch()` of the same endpoint, create a blob from the response, call `URL.createObjectURL()` on the blob to get a url, and pass that url to the `window.open()` call.  Ie I have something like:

```
fetch('http://somedomain.com/rest/getMyPdf', {
    method: 'PUT', 
    ... some headers & the body ...
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});
```

This works in Firefox (I get a PDF in a new window), but in Chrome you just see the raw ASCII of the PDF contents (ie `%PDF-1.3.....`).

I’m guessing this is some sort of content-type issue, ie if I could set the content type on the url, then Chrome would interpret the response as a PDF.  Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that did it (didn't need the `Uint8Array` though, just the raw result from `arrayBuffer`).  Want to flesh that out & add as an answer & I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var data = response.arraybuffer();
```

Then create a Blob from there [with the right content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)

```
var = new Blob(data, 'application/pdf');
```