# Unable to get pdf file type along with other image types as create a zip file using angular6

Tags: angular, pdf, typescript-typings

Here I am having file types and download collection of file types as a zip file all the image format is working fine except "pdf" file the downloaded file contains "filename.undefined" (pdf file only). other files extension same(filename.jpg, filname.png, filename.gif)
[image]

`readonly FILE_TYPE = {
    "image/png": "png",
    "image/jpeg": "jpg",
    "image/jpg": "jpg",
    "image/gif": "gif",
    "image/pdf": "pdf"
  };`

Is this correct way mentioned pdf file type what I mentioned "image/pdf": "pdf"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME media type for pdf is `application/pdf` and not `image/pdf`.

See [Proper MIME media type for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)